# Android String.format locale set explicitly to US but Persian numbers are used for Integer

Tags: java, android, locale, digits, persian

The title explains it all.

```
String method = String.format(
            "SELECT studymap.id,studymap.title,studymap.zorder,studymap.hierarchy_id,studymap.book_id," +
                    "studymap.abstract,studymap.type,studymap.free_view,studymap.localpath,studymap.flags," +
                    "studymap.visit_status,downloads.status as download_status,downloads.studymap_id,studymap.publish_status "+
                    "FROM studymap LEFT JOIN downloads ON studymap.id = downloads.studymap_id" +
                    " WHERE studymap.book_id = %d ORDER BY studymap.zorder", book.ID);
```

book.ID is integers, but i still get this error on some devices:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ۵۴۵ (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT studymap.id,studymap.title,studymap.zorder,studymap.hierarchy_id,studymap.book_id,studymap.abstract,studymap.type,studymap.free_view,studymap.localpath,studymap.flags,studymap.visit_status,downloads.status as download_status,downloads.studymap_id,studymap.publish_status,hierarchy.is_owned FROM studymap LEFT JOIN downloads ON studymap.id = downloads.studymap_id LEFT JOIN hierarchy ON hierarchy.id = studymap.hierarchy_id WHERE studymap.hierarchy_id = ۵۴۵ ORDER BY studymap.zorder at com.nemo.kaman_android.core.ag.run(SqliteKit.java:303)
```

SqliteKit.java(303):

```
Cursor cursor = KamanDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

I even set applications default locale in MyApplication.java

```
Locale locale = new Locale(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage());
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

but these aren't enough apparently

I was building queries like this a while ago:

```
"SELECT sum(badge) ... " + year_filter + ...
```

and it was crashing with same errors on some devices.
but after using format, some of the calls gets fixed and some don't.
I don't know what what i'm thinking.

**Edit 2:**
I thought maybe i put a utf8 persian character in the middle of query somewhere that makes the integers come persian, but as now i can see in my crash logs, same kind of exceptions happen on different queries on different devices, i just can't put everything together,
one of the devices has default "farsi" locale and the other "en", at least thats what Acralyzer thinks they have.

Comment: do you print the string after format?  I think the sql String is same.

Comment: i don't print it, i exec the sql query, that is the exception thrown by sqlite

Comment: eh, could you print the sql String? And give the full error tracks.I suspect your problem is not at String.format.